# what are all the ways to transfer image data from iPhone to ASP .NET server

Tags: ios, image, image-processing

What are all the ways to transfer image data from iPHone to ASP .NET server.
 One way is converting image data to base64 and sending it to server. But Base64 conversion will increase 1MB image to approximately 1.3 MB (Ya we can compress and send a lesser size too) .But eager to know is there any other way of sending the image data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a [multipart HTTP POST request](http://chxo.com/be2/20050724_93bf.html), you can send the file without Base64 encoding.